# Why is my SQL code putting everyone in each job under each project

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to create a result where it lists everyone with a job, the project name,  their first name, last name, and enter date when they started working. While being sorted by enter date ascending. However my query keeps putting all employees under each position and each project.

This is the code being used in my database.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
  DeptNo CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  DeptName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  DeptLocation VARCHAR(30) NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (DeptNo));

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE  (
  EmpNo INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  EmpFirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  EmpLastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  DeptNo CHAR(4) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo),
  FOREIGN KEY (DeptNo) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (DeptNo));

CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
  ProjNo CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  ProjName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  ProjBudget DECIMAL(12,2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ProjNo));

CREATE TABLE WORKSON (
  EmpNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ProjNo CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  WonJob VARCHAR (15) NULL,
  WonEnterDate DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo, ProjNo),
  FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EmpNo),  
  FOREIGN KEY (ProjNo) REFERENCES PROJECT (ProjNo));

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(25348, 'Matthew', 'Smith','d3');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(10102, 'Ann', 'Jones','d3');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(18316, 'John', 'Barrimore', 'd1');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(29346, 'James', 'James', 'd2');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(9031, 'Elsa', 'Bertoni', 'd2');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(2581, 'Elke', 'Hansel', 'd2');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(28559, 'Sybill', 'Moser', 'd1');

INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES ('d1', 'research','Dallas');
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES ('d2', 'accounting', 'Seattle');
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES ('d3', 'marketing', 'Dallas');

INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES ('p1', 'Apollo', 120000.00);
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES ('p2', 'Gemini', 95000.00);
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES ('p3', 'Mercury', 186500.00);

INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (10102,'p1', 'analyst', '2006.10.1');
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (10102, 'p3', 'manager', '2008.1.1');
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (25348, 'p2', 'clerk', '2007.2.15');
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (18316, 'p2', NULL, '2007.6.1');
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (29346, 'p2', NULL, '2006.12.15');
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (2581, 'p3', 'analyst', '2007.10.15');
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (9031, 'p1', 'manager', '2007.4.15');
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (28559, 'p1', NULL, '2007.8.1');
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (28559, 'p2', 'clerk', '2008.2.1');
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (9031, 'p3', 'clerk', '2006.11.15'); 
INSERT INTO WORKSON VALUES (29346, 'p1','clerk', '2007.1.4');
```

This is my query that place all employees in every job under every position. Instead of the positions they actually work in.

```
SELECT WORKSON.WonJob, PROJECT.ProjName, EMPLOYEE.EmpFirstName, EMPLOYEE.EmpLastName, WORKSON.WonEnterDate
    FROM WORKSON, PROJECT, EMPLOYEE
    WHERE WonJob IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY WonEnterDate ASC
```

Comment: Please show us your desired results.

Comment: [tag:mysqli] is used for [tag:mysql] not [tag:sql-server], please correct your tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually join the tables using predicates, rather than just cross-joining everything together.

It's best to do this using explicit join syntax, rather than the deprecated comma-join.

```sql
SELECT
  w.WonJob,
  p.ProjName,
  e.EmpFirstName,
  e.EmpLastName,
  w.WonEnterDate
FROM WORKSON AS w
JOIN PROJECT AS p ON p.ProjNo = w.ProjNo
JOIN EMPLOYEE AS e ON e.EmpNo = w.EmpNo
WHERE w.WonJob IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  w.WonEnterDate;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/nyMyA6E5)